# method to draw circular buttons in pyqt5

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

i would like to try to create a row of circular buttons with a method different with the one that uses setStyleSheets to define the color, the thickness and so on. The code that I managed to get with that method is the following:

```
self.button_list = []

    for i in range(10):
        button = QPushButton("{}".format(i+1), self)
        button.setFixedSize(QSize(50, 50))
        button.setStyleSheet("border : 1px solid black;background-color : green; color: yellow; border-radius : 25px")

        self.button_list.append(button)

        mainlayout.addWidget(button, i)
```

With what other method can I achieve the same results of circular buttons?

Comment: Subclass the widget and override its [`paintEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent). Then do some research about drawing/painting a custom widget, and take your time (lot of time and patience) to read all the related documentation, starting from: [QWidget](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html), [QAbstractButton](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html), [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html), [QStyle](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html) and all related pages linked in those documents.

Comment: is the paintEvent also to associate with QPushButton?

Comment: It's called for ***any*** widget: that's how Qt paints everything.